# Ruby object to Java object

Tags: java, ruby

I want to create an object from a Ruby program and store it in an SQL database as a blob. I then want to be able to read this blob directly into a Java program at a later date. I understand that these blobs will probably be incompatible. How can I go about making a Java-readable blob from Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use json (xml, yaml) format to store object as string. And parse it in java.

Comment: How fast would this be for exceptionally large objects, though? Say ~100mb.

Comment: Don't know, try it. But I don't think there is good way to serialize native ruby object and deserialize it as java object. Even if it's possible, I doubt it would be fast.

Comment: It wouldn't be as fast as it would be without serializing/Deserializing. The best way is to benchmark it and see how it works for you.

Comment: OK, thanks. Accepting this answer as, although the other one provides helpful links, this one also answered my follow-up.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Serialize ruby object](http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/serializing-and-deserializing-objects-with-ruby/) to YAML (or JSON, XML etc)
2. Save it in the DB
3. [Deserialize it from YAML to Java object](http://yamlbeans.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/), it is much faster than (de)serializing json. See the benchmark [here](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki/)